# namespaces and class extends

Tags: php, class, namespaces

Im trying to figure out how namespaces works in PHP, but havent really been lucky

Hope somebody could tell me what Im doing wrong here :)

## code

```
require_once 'Vatcode.php';
$Vatcode = new \resource\Vatcode();
```

## Vatcode.php

```
namespace resource;

require_once Ini::get('path/class').'/Resource.php';

class Vatcode extends Resource {
    public function __construct(){
        echo 'works!';
    }
}
```

## Rescource.php

```
namespace resource;

class Resource {

}
```

## error

```
Fatal error:  Class 'resource\Ini' not found in Vatcode.php
```

Comment: You use nowhere `new Ini()` in the code you gave...

Comment: the question has been edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's just a problem of namespace.
Your class Vatcode is in namesapce ressource. If, in the file of VatCode declaration you use `nameofclas::...` or `new nameofclass()` it will try to get the class in namespace ressource.
If you want to use the class Ini inside your document you have two solutions :

first give the full qualified name :

```
require \namespace\of\ini\Ini::get('path/class').'/Resource.php';
```

second using the "use" keyworld before using the get method :

```
use \namespace\of\ini\Ini;
require_once Ini::get('path/class').'/Resource.php';
```

In any case, if Ini is in "no namespace" (*global namespace* is the accurate word) you just has to use the solutions I gave you but only with `\Ini` instead of `\namespace\of\ini\Ini`

Comment: Ini class is not in any namespace

Comment: ok.. I assume from your answer that you can have namespaces in more than one dimension? `\first_level\second_level\the_class`

Comment: @clarkk: All classes are in namespaces.  If one is not explicitly defined, then the class is said to be in the _global namespace_, and it can be referenced like `\YourClass` (note the leading backslash).